# how to manage exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

I need to extract some data from an external database.
I don't have access to all data, that's why I need to handle the access exception to not block the execution of my application.
This is the function to extract documents for example :

```
public IDocumentListCollection getDocumentCollection(string ProjectID, SearchQuery query)
        {
            try
            {
                return DocumentService().FindDocuments("", ProjectID, true, true);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                ...
            }
    }
```

What do i need to write in the catch bloc to satisfy my purpose ?

Comment: What exception gets thrown when you access data that you are not allow to connect to?

Comment: PermissionDeniedException

Comment: Then you should catch PermissionDeniedException instead of Exception. That way if something besides PermissionDeniedException gets thrown you will find out about it.

Comment: Impossible to answer without more specific information *how* the data is organized and how you are querying for it.

Comment: What do you want your method to do if it can't access the required external data? Return an empty collection? Throw another exception? This really depends on what you want.

Comment: No i just want it to continue extracting the other data that i have permission to see, and if not ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to *"handle"*<sup>1</sup> it inside `FindDocuments`.

In the case of your current `try...catch`-block all you can do is:

1. Log the exception
2. Hide the exception (by not calling `throw;`)

You cannot restart or pick up where `FindDocuments` left off.

> [What] do I need to write in the `catch`-block to satisfy my purpose?

Nothing will satisfy the purpose of "ignoring" or "skipping" permission exceptions *inside* `FindDocuments`. You will need to edit that method instead.

<sub>1. By default you should not *handle* exceptions at all.</sub>

Comment: I can't, FindDocuments is a function already prepared in a dll that i import in my code. I just use it to extract the data that i need.

Comment: Unfortunately you've answered your own question.

Comment: So i can't do smth to ignore that exception and continue extracting the data that i have access to ?

Comment: Not externally no. At the point you've caught the exception, `FindDocuments` is already "gone" / has already "exited" (so to speak).

Comment: So what do you propose ? how can i handle that ? 
I appreciate your help :)

Comment: You cannot handle it unless you can, (a) keep it from requesting data from databases it does not have access to, (b) edit `FindDocuments` to handle it properly.

Comment: Yes, im looking for a way to do what u proposed in option (a)

Comment: We do not have enough information in your code to hazard a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You have two good options and a bad one

either return a standard IDocumentListCollection in the catch block or remove the "try {} catch {}" and let the function throw the exception (and deal with it at a higher level)

the third option is return null, if applicable, but would void the whole exception-handle thing

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
public IDocumentListCollection getDocumentCollection(string ProjectID, SearchQuery query)
{
     IDocumentListCollection rtnVal;
     try
     {
        rtnVal = DocumentService().FindDocuments("", ProjectID, true, true);
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         rtnVal = new DocumentListCollection(); //Or any other stubbed version.
     }

     return rtnVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, click on "Debug" menu in Visual Studio, then select "Exceptions" and switch off all notifications ("Thrown" column). Now your application execution will not be terminated while debugging (if your exception was handled, of course)